# How to use JobID that is declared in another job definition file in spring batch

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch

I have 3 jobs. They are `Job1, Job2 and Job3`.
`Job1` have to run `Job2` and `Job3` in parallel.
These jobs are defined in separated job definition files as followings.

Job1.xml

```
<batch:job id="Job1" restartable="true" >
        <batch:step id="step1" next="split">
            <batch:tasklet ref="job1.stp01" />
        </batch:step>

        <batch:split id="split">
            <batch:flow>
                <batch:step id="flow1" >
                    <batch:job ref="Job2" job-launcher="simpleJobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="defaultJobParametersExtractor"/>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:flow>

            <batch:flow>
                <batch:step id="flow2">
                    <batch:job ref="Job3" job-launcher="simpleJobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="defaultJobParametersExtractor"/>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:flow>
        </batch:split>

    </batch:job>
```

Job2.xml

```
<batch:job id="Job2" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="Job2.Step01">
            <batch:tasklet ref="job2.stp01" />
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

Job3.xml

```
<batch:job id="Job3" restartable="true">
    <batch:step id="Job3.Step01">
        <batch:tasklet ref="job3.stp01" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The problem is when I start the tomcat server, the following problem was occurred.

```
13:33:56,875 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flow1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'Job2' while setting bean property 'job'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'Job2' is defined
```

But it was okay when all jobs are declared in only one job definition file.
So, let me know that Is there a way to solve this problem.

Comment: is a simple question, but have you the imports of the other spring context file? (e.g. <import resource="classpath*:META-INF/Job2.xml" /> )

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration

```
<import resource="classpath*:META-INF/Job2.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:META-INF/Job3.xml" />

<batch:job id="Job1" restartable="true" >
    <batch:step id="step1" next="split">
        <batch:tasklet ref="job1.stp01" />
    </batch:step>

    <batch:split id="split">
        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="flow1" >
                <batch:job ref="Job2" job-launcher="simpleJobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="defaultJobParametersExtractor"/>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>

        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="flow2">
                <batch:job ref="Job3" job-launcher="simpleJobLauncher" job-parameters-extractor="defaultJobParametersExtractor"/>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>
    </batch:split>

</batch:job>
```

Comment: Thank you, Xstian. I already tried this, But I found this error.  `Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.DuplicateJobException: A job configuration with this name [Job2] was already registered`

Comment: Importing resource is only okay for spring batch command line mode and not okay for spring batch console UI mode.

Comment: If you add more details, we can help you better to solve also this problem :) ... probably in the full spring context there is another job with the same name.

Comment: In fact, there are only 3 job definition files and related java classes. In java classes , there are only System.out.print log output for testing. There are not business logic. Requirement is to run one or more jobs in parallel.

Comment: Can you add, how import all job definition xml? and error stack trace .. is strange because it seems that everything is well configured

Comment: In fact, when running the spring batch by command line, `<importing resource>` is works fine. But when starting the tomcat server to run the spring batch admin console, `<importing resource>` seem to re-register or define the job again. So this problem occurred.

Comment: have you already seen this [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/42315-duplicatejobexception)? seems that is your solution